# Display backlight won't turn on after suspended state (Hp omen 15)

Tags: suspend, laptop, hp, backlight

When ever my laptop is coming out of a suspended state the back light will not turn on and I have to reboot the entire machine to fix it. I've tried many things including installing a fresh version of Ubuntu. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

#### Update 10/10/2020

This post gets a decent amount of views so I'm going to update it with all the latest info I have.

I talked to hp support and many different communities and HP is saying that whatever special bios stuff they did really doesn't like to play nice when trying to do things like going into a suspended state on anything other than windows.

Comment: Have you tried pressing the key (or keys combo) to enable/disable the backlight?

Comment: I dont think that there is a button combo to turn on or off the display backlight

Comment: I tough you were asking about the keyboard backlight.

Comment: haha, I wish it was just the keyboard back light. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Some HP Omen models have FN+F1 and FN+F2 to control the screen backlight. Does yours have it and if so have you tried increasing it? This HP forum thread reports this shortcuts not working (Win10) and the problem solved by reinstalling the graphics drivers: https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Video-Display-and-Touch/Screen-brightness-change-fn-keys-not-working-OMEN-by-HP-15/td-p/6455860